# Select files in vim fuzzy finder without using arrow keys?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I recently discovered the fuzzyfinder plugin for vim.  It's CoverageFile functionality is perfect, with one niggling detail.

It will list the files, and the only way I know of to select one of them is to move my hand over to the arrow keys and "key down" to the file and then press .

The entries in the menu have a number beside them, which leads me to believe there's a shortcut for opening the file.  The problem is, I can't really find documentation on it.  I've pored over some of the docs for fuzzyfinder, but they only describe how to open the selected item in various ways (split, vsplit, tab, etc), not how to actually select the item.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it, it's Control-N/Control-P, makes sense :) – Fred Oct 27 at 17:25

Answer (score 0):

You can type out the name of the file as well. This will work like and incremental search, shortening the fuzzyfinder file list until a unique match is found.

The number next to the file name is the buffer number so for example typing `:buffer 23` will open buffer 23.

Comment: I don't think that's the solution, unless I'm just missing something.  Typing :buffer or buffer just prompts fuzzyfinder to look for a file with that text in the filename.

Comment: I found it, it's Control-N/Control-P, makes sense :)